# tvOS GameController At what point does GCController.controllers become populated after launch?

Tags: objective-c, swift, tvos, apple-tv, gamecontroller

I'm trying to read the `GCController.controllers()` array after my app has launched to know which controllers were already connected to the AppleTV at app launch. But `GCController.controllers().count` is 0 until some point after `viewDidAppear` gets called on my initial UIViewController. Does anyone know the definitive point by which you can check `GCController.controllers()` to know that it has been populated with the currently connected controllers?

I am aware of the need to register for controller connection notifications with;

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleControllerDidConnectNotification:"   , name: GCControllerDidConnectNotification   , object: nil)
```

But that is for later after launch. First I need to know which ones are already connected. Anyone know?

Comment: Anyone know if & how I could key-value observe GCController.controllers() in swift? Anyone? Bueller? ..Bueller?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `startWirelessControllerDiscoveryWithCompletionHandler` on `viewDidLoad` and then check `GCController.controllers()` on `viewWillAppear` that seem to work for the game app I just finished.

Docs:

> **After your app has finished launching**, the operating system
>   automatically creates a list of connected controllers. Call the
>   controllers class method to retrieve an array of GCController objects
>   for all connected controllers. Next, use these objects to configure
>   the controllers or read the controller’s inputs. If there are no
>   connected controllers or **you call this method while your app is
>   launching, the array will be empty**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no dice.

Comment: That should work, as long as you are not calling `controllers()` while the app is launching.  I updated my answer to include info from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

GCController will generate GCControllerDidConnectNotification notifications for each controller, including those connected to the device prior to launch.  If you're not getting notifications for already-connected controllers, confirm the following:

- Double-check that it is paired and turned on
- Make sure it is a MFi controller.